# Data Labelling in Azure - Images not sorted

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I am labelling image data using Azure Data Labelling service.
My images are sorted in a blob container.
I would like to tag the images in the order they are sorted (which is the chronological order). However, Azure seems to mix them before showing them up.
Does anyone know how to configure that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What ever may be the name of the image we uploaded, but when we upload image into the datastore it will directly rename all the images and it will show in an ascending order by creation date. The order of images will be based on the size of the image which we uploaded. The final set of images will be based on the ascending order of the labeled duration taken to label the data.

[image]

[image]

It is not an issue of sorting. It will be taken into consideration according to the size of image when the time of upload and then the time taken to label the dataset images.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design to reduce bias by the labeler/analyst